# Error when i try to make a join in adonis: missing FROM-clause entry for table "book

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to make a query using query builder adonis, but i'm getting this error:

> select * from "books" inner join "book_unit" on "book"."id" =
>   "book_unit"."id" - missing FROM-clause entry for table "book"

This is my query:

```
async show({ request }){
    await Database
    .table('books')
    .from('books')
    .innerJoin('book_unit','book.id', 'book_unit.id' )
}
```

Why i'm getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```js
async show({ request }){
    await Database
    .table('books')
    .innerJoin('book_unit','books.id', 'book_unit.book_id' )
}
```

*Please tell me if this is the expected result.*